# How to change the number of minorticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create such figure (https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-DCFuRHtqTmk/VFq_cf0Cj4I/AAAAAAAAETA/hDPE8N8LLDE/w682-h695-no/figure.png) using PLT.MATSHOW with labeled majorticks (in range from 0 to 20 with step = 1), unlabeled minorticks (from 0.5 to 18.5 with step = 1) and minorgrids.

Here is my code, but something is wrong with it (it draws more lines than I need and I do not know how to change number of minorticks):

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

S0 = np.ones([20,20], int)
S = np.copy(S0)
Mx = np.shape(S)[0]
My = np.shape(S)[1]

for x in range(Mx):
    for y in range(My):
            S[x,y]=2*random.randint(2)-1

plt.matshow(S, fignum = None, alpha = 0.75, cmap = "summer")
plt.xticks(range(0, Mx, 1))
plt.yticks([i for i in range(0, My)])
plt.grid(which = 'minor', ls = '-')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.show()
```

How should I rewrite it to solve my problem?
Thank you for the help! (:

Comment: Need to be more specific than "There is something wrong with it" - what exactly is happening that is the problem?

Comment: I believe he wants the code to draw a black grid, with the squares it creates being randomly filled with green or yellow. The problem is that instead, it draws several other lines instead. This seems to be from a misunderstanding of what major and minor tick lines are.

Comment: The problem is that it draws a few other lines (minorlines or minortricks) with step 0.2 instead of step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this solves your problem.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

S0 = np.ones([20,20], int)
S = np.copy(S0)
Mx = np.shape(S)[0]
My = np.shape(S)[1]

for x in range(Mx):
    for y in range(My):
            S[x,y]=2*random.randint(2)-1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.matshow(S,alpha=0.75, cmap="summer", interpolation="none")

ax.set_xticks([i+0.5 for i in range(Mx)])
ax.set_yticks([i+0.5 for i in range(My)])

ax.set_xticklabels(range(Mx))
ax.set_yticklabels(range(My))

#plt.grid(which = 'minor', ls = '-')
plt.grid(which = 'major', ls = '-')

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.show()
```

The changes that i have made are threefold; the first replaces the grid with the major grid lines, and the second is that i have moved the ticks and corresponding labels by 0.5, so that they match the boundaries. The third is to remove interpolation in the `matshow` command. This all gives this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. It much more better now. (: But why lines and the border between two colors do not coincide (sometimes)?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean that the line does not appear consistent down the page? I would guess that this is a sub pixel effect; pixels are notmally RGB; green is (OFF ON OFF), yellow is (ON ON OFF), black is (OFF OFF OFF). So black will look blacker when it's next to green. Or it might just be some kind of illusion about the perception of characters.

Comment: Or it could be an antialiasing thing.

Comment: Some squares are completely yellow inside, some - are  completely green, but there are also a few squares which contain approximately 5% of oposite color on the bottom (for example, green square will have yellow stripe on the bottom).

Comment: I do not have this in my version; the first answer i gave had this problem, and i then subsequently updated it by adding `interpolation="none"` to `matshow()`.

Comment: Also, fyi, if you put links to images you want to include in yor posts, then nine times out of ten someone will edit them in for you.

Comment: Thank you, Will for the help! (: Here is the link for the figure (https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-VoDg0xRaY2w/VFq_cajgrvI/AAAAAAAAES8/4Ut1p7yA3xw/w461-h385-no/1.jpg) which I got using your code. Discrepancies are marked with red ellips. Addition of the interpolation="none" in matshow() does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found how to solve the problem and get what I want. Thank you, Will, for the help!
If someone else knows how to get the final result using a different method, I would appretiate if you let me know.

Here is new code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator

S0 = np.ones([20,20], int)
S = np.copy(S0)
Mx = np.shape(S)[0]
My = np.shape(S)[1]

for x in range(Mx):
    for y in range(My):
            S[x,y]=2*random.randint(2)-1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.matshow(S, alpha = .75, cmap = "summer")

ax.set_xticklabels(range(-1,Mx))
ax.set_yticklabels(range(-1,My))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.xaxis.grid(True,'minor', lw = 1.5, ls = '-')
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'minor', lw = 1.5, ls = '-')

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is very odd, i tried exactly the solution you've mentioned here, and it did not work for me, but the solution i have works for me and not for you. What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: I installed matplotlib-1.4.2.win32-py2.7 version! And it really can be odd, because I have just recently started to learn Python. And the main problem: I know what I want, but I do not know how to make it or even explain /: